# Couldn't find action or result. No result defined for action in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, actionresult, dmi, struts2-codebehind-plugin

I have configured the annotation to return the values as text. But it's giving me the error: `could not find action or result`.

**Console error:**

```
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - Could not find action or result
/part!finder.xhtml
No result defined for action action.PartAction and result success
```

**Action:**

```
@Action(value="part!finder", results = {
    @Result(name="SUCCESS", type="stream", params = {"contentType", "text/html", "inputName", "inputStream"}),
    @Result(name="success", type="stream", params = {"contentType", "text/html", "inputName", "inputStream"})
}) 
public String finder() {
  try {
    inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(finder1().getBytes());
  }
  catch(Exception e) { }
    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

Comment: That `action.PartAction` you are trying to execute is not defined anywhere...

Comment: No action.PartAction is class path...like com.aa.action.PartAction and PartAction is action class name.

Answer (score 1):

Change the action name, that is a `value` attribute in the `@Action` annotation to `value="part"`. `!` is a special character used to separate action name and method name in the URL. But not in the action mapping. By adding `!` in the action name mapping you make your action unreachable to action mapper that is searching for the action config that contains names without `!`. This char splits the action name and a method name, so it is inappropriate mapping in your action configuration.

BTW, when constructing URL and you have [DMI](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation) turned on (which is by default is on) then better use a `method` attribute to `url` or `submit` tag and the correct url that maps to your action will be created after the JSP is rendered (result is processed). You could check the HTML outputed to the browser to see the source HTML code for the page. And you might find you action that is mapped to the (not default) method is prefixed by the `!` sign. You could explicitly or via tags add the method to the action URL to execute method other than mapped with the action.

Comment: Thanks Roman. Thats good info.but this not convention plugin here have used codebehind plugin.@Action(value="part", results = {
    @Result(name="SUCCESS", type="stream", params = {"contentType", "text/html", "inputName", "inputStream"})
       })

Comment: @user2444474 You should edit the question and say that you are using codebehind plugin, however it's deprecated but ppl at least will know about it. It uses different annotations with the same name as convention plugin, different attributes. It's really hard to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DMI, apply `@Action` at the *class* level, and let DMI do the rest.

If you're annotating at the action level, declare a unique action name and don't use DMI.

(Or its syntax; it's confusing.)